# There is a class for objective c like IsolatedStorage for. Net?

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, objective-c, windows-phone-8

IsolatedStorage its a class in .net for windowsphone that enables local storage, without database.

Exist a similar class to make or worship me in objective c?

Comment: There are lots of ways to save data locally without databases in Objective-C. Describe your data and how you use it, and maybe someone can answer.

Comment: `IsolatedStorage` is used for file I/O operations. You can check this tutor for iOS: [Working with Files on iOS 4 (iPhone)](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_on_iOS_4_%28iPhone%29). `NSFileManager` is the closest equivalent in iOS

Comment: Thnks @AlaaMasoud, i will check it!

Comment: @TomHarrington i need to save simple data, like flags (labels, version, etc), very simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like  `NSUserDefaults` will suit your purpose. It's dead simple. You use a known Key to Set/Get objects ( like that of `NSDictionary` )

```
// Setting a String value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: localPath forKey:@"NSStringMediaLocalpath"

// and Getting a string
NSString *localMediaPath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSStringMediaLocalpath"];
```

You should provide default values in your App init method, as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *initialValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

 // Careful with BOOL. Is actually a NSNumber object 
[initialValues setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"NSManagedObjectContextSaveisAutoSave"];

[initialValues setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:20] forKey:@"NSURLConnectionTimeoutPeriod"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:initialValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

Many core classes like `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSString` include methods to read/write their data to/from files directly. Literally, just tell an array to write itself to a file, and it does so. Tell `NSArray` to create an instance from a file, and it does so.

There's also a scheme called `NSCoding` that any class can implement to assist in converting itself to/from `NSData`. `NSData` can write itself directly to files, so this covers any class where instances can be serialized into a binary blob.

Specialized classes often have their own file conveniences. For example, `UIImage` can be initialized directly from any file containing a compatible image format (which is anything common-- PNG, JPG, GIF, etc, there are a lot).

If you need finer grained control, you can use `NSFileHandle` to read/write arbitrary data streams to/from files. `NSFileManager` also has methods to read and write files.

This is all just at the Cocoa Touch level. On iOS you also have access to the entire Unix system of reading and writing files, if that's what you prefer.